# onClick change content text + class

Tags: jquery, html, css

My problem at the moment is this, I've finally made further progress but I can't make it change it's `background-color` and `color` and the text says `Hide` after the content slides up again.

I got a button that shows content when you press it, the text on the button says `Show` and the background-color is gray but when you click it, it should say Hide with a green background.

jQuery

```
$(".portfolio_show_content").hide("slow");
    $(".portfolio_show").on('click', function() {
    $(".portfolio_show_content").hide();
    $(this).parent().find(".portfolio_show_content").slideToggle();
    $(this).html('Hide');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="single_item">
    <h3>Standby overlay</h3><button class="right portfolio_show">Show</button>
    <p class="portfolio_show_content">This overlay comes in either basic or advanced, advanced includes animations and more styling-/effects.</p>
</div>
```

Link: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzgajurb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an active class that does the same as your `:hover` and toggle that class and the text

```
$(".portfolio_show_content").hide("slow");

$(".portfolio_show").on('click', function () {
    var el  = $(this).parent().find(".portfolio_show_content").slideToggle(),
        el2 = $(this).html(function(_, htm) {
                return htm == 'Hide' ? 'Show' : 'Hide';
              }).toggleClass('active')

    $(".portfolio_show_content").not(el).hide();
    $(".portfolio_show").not(el2).removeClass('active')
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fzgajurb/3/)

Comment: This was something I wanted exactly, but there is slightly problem with the code. When you press on the other button istead of pressing the hide button the active class + hide text shows instead of sliding to it's original state. @adeneo

Comment: @P.Samuel - oh, okay, didn't even notice, but it's fixed now !

Comment: Added $(".portfolio_show").not(el2).html('Show') to the bottom line as well, the show text was bugged too. I appreciate all the help and thanks a lot for taking your time to answer to this question. @adaneo

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
     $('button funtion').on('click', function(event) {

                $('sample1').className;
                $('sample1').removeClassName('hidden');
                $('sample1').className;

                $('sample2').className;
                $('sample2').addClassName('hidden');
                $('sample2').className;

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

i changed a little your code to make it work. 
http://jsfiddle.net/fzgajurb/2/

Basically is the same, but added some lines to make it work.

```
       $(".portfolio_show").on('click', function() {
            $(".portfolio_show_content").hide();
            $(".portfolio_show").html('Show');
            $(".portfolio_show").removeClass('green');
            $(this).parent().find(".portfolio_show_content").slideToggle();
            $(this).addClass('green');
            $(this).html('Hide');
        });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but I decided the answer that I accepted suited me more, but I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(".portfolio_show_content").hide("slow");
$(".portfolio_show").on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().find(".portfolio_show_content").slideToggle();
    $(this).html($(this).html()=='Hide'?'Show':'Hide');
});
```

```css
 div.single_item {
     background-color: #ffffff;
     width: 270px;
     height: auto;
     padding: 10px;
     margin: 7px 0 0 0;
 }
 div.single_item p {
     padding: 0 9px;
     font-size: 9pt;
     display: none;
 }
 div.single_item button {
     border: 0;
     width: 50px;
     height: 25px;
     border-radius: 20px;
     background-color: #EEE;
     color: #BCBCBC;
     font-weight: 600;
     padding: 0px 0 0 0;
     font-size: 8pt;
     margin: -30px 0 15px 222px;
     cursor: pointer;
     position: absolute;
 }
 div.single_item button:hover {
     background-color: #38B587;
     color: #1B6145;
 }
 div.single_item button:focus {
     outline: none;
 }
 div.single_item button div.active {
     content:"Hide";
     background-color: #38B587 !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="single_item">
     <h3>Standby overlay</h3>
    <button class="right portfolio_show">Show</button>
    <p class="portfolio_show_content">This overlay comes in either basic or advanced, advanced includes animations and more styling-/effects.</p>
</div>
<div class="single_item">
     <h3>Standby overlay</h3>
    <button class="right portfolio_show">Show</button>
    <p class="portfolio_show_content">This overlay comes in either basic or advanced, advanced includes animations and more styling-/effects.</p>
</div>
```